# @QueryParam always showing null

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a RESTful service. This takes in two parameters a start-date and end-date.

If I use @RequestParam annotation I get what I need. But if I use @QueryParam I noticed that its always showing as null even when passed.

Here is my resource:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/usage-query", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation(value = "Available Sessions - JSON Body", notes = "GET method for unique users")
public List<DTO> getUsageByDate(@QueryParam("start-date") final String startDate,
        @QueryParam("end-date") String endDate)
         throws BadParameterException {
    return aaaService.findUsageByDate2(startDate, endDate);

}
```

Then here is my service:

```
    List<DTO> findUsageByDate(String startDate, String endDate) throws BadParameterException;
```

Then here is my service implementation:

```
public List<DTO> findUsageByDate(String startDate, String endDate) throws BadParameterException {
    return aaaDao.getUsageByDate(startDate, endDate);

}
```

Here is my DAO:

```
    List<DTO> getUsageByDate(String startDate, String endDate) throws BadParameterException;
```

Here is my DAO Implementation:

```
@Override
public List<DTO> getUsageByDate(String startDate, String endDate) throws BadParameterException {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(
            "select * from usage where process_time >= :start_date");

    if(endDate!= null)
    {
        sql.append(" and process_time < :end_date");
    }


    sql.append(" limit 10");
    System.out.println(sql.toString());
    SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("start_date", startDate)
            .addValue("end_date", endDate);
    try {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql.toString(), namedParameters,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<DTO>(AAAUsageDTO.class));

    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        throw new BadParameterException();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Probably something obvious

Comment: and what is the service endpoint you are calling for both requestparam and query param?

Comment: Sorry about that, I put the code and missed the bit you need :-) Here it is: GET /v1/usage/usage-query?start-date=2016-01-01;end-date=2016-03-01 HTTP/1.1

Comment: there is an ampersand & between start-date and end-date?

Comment: I am confused isn't that what is supposed to happen? If i use postman that is how it generates the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I use `@RequestParam` annotation I get what I need. But if I use `@QueryParam` I noticed that its always showing as null even when passed.

Because you are using Spring MVC, which has *no connection whatsoever* to JAX-RS, which `@QueryParam` is for. Spring uses `@RequestParam`. If you're going to use Spring, I suggest you get rid of your JAX-RS dependency so you don't get confused about what you can and can't use.

Comment: Thank you so much yes doh that makes a lot of sense

Comment: I am using EJB and I have this problem with @QueryParam !

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@QueryParam("end-date")` with `@QueryParam("endDate")`. This will work. But, I would suggest you to use `@RequestParam` from `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation`, the reason for which is well explained in the answer by Paul Samsotha.